# Can I use Google's Polymer platform and legally make a profit?

Tags: polymer

I have developed a Webapp using Google's Polymer platform. I have since realised that I can make a profit using this Webapp but am inexperienced when it comes to legalities. Is anyone simply allowed to use their platforms for any purpose? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Polymer's license can be found here: http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt . It's what's known as a BSD license. Wikipedia has more information on this style of BSD license here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause